# Remember next and previous pages using a stack

Tags: php, stack

If you have an array of page names such as the one shown below:

```
    $array = ["home.php", "about.php", "contact.php"];
```

The user would land on "home.php" and have a button to go to the next page which would be "about.php". The about page would then have a previous button that goes to "home.php" and a next button that will go to "contact.php".

I am trying to use a Stack for this by pushing and popping values but am having no luck. I appreciate if anyone suggests alternatives to this but I want to use a stack.

Comment: *I am trying to use a Stack for this by pushing and popping values but am having no luck.* - Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Assign the array in the session variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_search to find the location of the current page inside the array. Then check if it has any neighbours, like this:

```
$array = ["home.php", "about.php", "contact.php"];

// Get the location of the current page in $array
$currentPageKey = array_search(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), $array);

// See if there is a key prior to this. If so, get it's value
$previousPage = array_key_exists($currentPageKey - 1, $array)
    ? $array[$currentPageKey - 1]
    : null;

// See if there is a key after this. If so, get it's value
$nextPage = array_key_exists($currentPageKey + 1, $array)
    ? $array[$currentPageKey + 1]
    : null;
```

Then you can do something like

```
if (!is_null($previousPage)) {
    echo '<a href="' . $previousPage . '">Previous</a>';
}

if (!is_null($nextPage)) { 
    echo '<a href="' . $nextPage . '">Next</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the array index of current page and build prev/next links accordingly:

```
    $array = ["home.php", "about.php", "contact.php"];
    $cp = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $ci = array_search($cp, $array);
    if($ci > 0){
        echo '<a href="'.$array[$ci-1].'">Prev page</a>';
    }
    if($ci < count($array)-1){
        echo '<a href="'.$array[$ci+1].'">Next page</a>';
    }
```